# Error when display an error message box. How can i display it?

Tags: c++, qt

I try to display an error message box but an error has been occurred. Can anyone help to check my coding?

```
void smtp_listener::pop3Stat(QString reply)
{

    print_D(FUNC);
    if(reply.contains("+OK"))
    {
        *t << "stat" <<"\r\n";
        t->flush();

        setState(POP3_Read);
    }
    else
    {
        print_E("ERROR :"+reply,FUNC,__LINE__);
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
        msgBox.setText("Please check it.");
        msgBox.exec();
        quitConn();
        setState(POP3_Quit);
    }
}
```

Error occurred as below:

```
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
ASSERT failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread.", file kernel\qwidget.cpp, line 1118
```

Comment: I believe the error messages fairly clearly state what the problem is. Unfortunately however, this is not enough code for me to be able to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be that your `smtp_listener` is being executed in another thread. A fairly simple Qt solution would be to not try displaying the error from `smtp_listener`. Instead give your `smtp_listener` an error signal. Connect this signal to a slot in your form which takes care of displaying the error. Qt's signal system will queue the signal for execution in the gui thread.

Answer (score 0):

Errors handling inside internal class methods is not a good practice.

The [@Eelke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944147/error-when-display-an-error-message-box-how-can-i-display-it#answer-53944491) solution is good if your class `smtp_listener` extends from QObject. But if you have a "clear" class (without any Qt relations, from external library, for example) you should **throw an exception** or **return an error value** (or an object representing the error state).

The approach provides you possibilities to organize the errors handling in one place (GUI class in your case). It is a good advantage both for you and other programmer who reads your code.

By the way you can combine [@Eelke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944147/error-when-display-an-error-message-box-how-can-i-display-it#answer-53944491) with mine using the code like this:

function returning an error:

```
int smtp_listener::pop3Stat(QString reply)
{
    if(reply.contains("+OK"))
    {
        *t << "stat" <<"\r\n";
        t->flush();

        setState(POP3_Read);
        return 0;  // success
    }

    return 1;      // return not null value with error
}
```

Code to handle the error:

```
/// slot to handle an error
/// don't forget to connect errorSignal with it
void MainWidnow::errorSignalSlot(int status)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Error code: " + QString::number(status));
}

void MainWidnow::button_onClick()
{
    int status = listener.pop3Stat(reply);

    if (status != 0) // not null value means error
    {
        emit(errorSignal(status)); // emit the signal with error code
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

widgets must created in main thread. I think you can pass any messages to main thread with signal/slot or event.